# Searching for variable length, delimited string based on the location of another string

Tags: excel, parsing, excel-formula

My first ever post...
Experienced with excel, but not with string searching/parsing...

I have a bunch of fields/cells of the following form:

```
"formid";s:4:"1001";s:11:"mkto_MRM_ID";s:6:"287227";s:15:"Activity_Name_m";s:59:"ca erwin data modeler community edition evaluation software";s:13:"CSU_Driver__c";s:0:""
```

The format is - Label, Length of upcoming string, String -
So, the label is `'formid'` the length of the upcoming field is 4 and the value is `'1001'`.

The number of labels and values can vary from field to field

What I want is to parse this data to find a half dozen Label/Value pairs out of this data and stick the values in a separate cell in a spreadsheet.

There are lots of delimiters, but I think the simplest approach - if it is doable - is to find a label I want, then return whatever is between the next set of quotes.

So in the above example i would search for `"mkto_MRM_ID"` then return what was between the next two quotes - in this case `"287227"`.

So I could have a half dozen formulas each in a column to the right of this data that parse the data looking with each formula looking for one of the half dozen labels I'm interested in then proceeding to return what is between the next two quotes.  Which could be nothing or a variable length string.

Hope that's clear.

Thanks in advance.

Phil

Comment: Please use correct formatting.  The contents of your cells/fields are not clear to comprehend.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and what sorts of problems you have run into.

Comment: So no help on answer below?  Do you have feedback on if that worked for you?  I did add a link to the sample I created on google docs...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I went ahead and solved the problem using formulas.  [Example spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Bi6bnRyv0ESnhjRHdCcDNwSEU)

I placed your text on a second sheet and then calculate the index of all the Quotes.  I ignore all of the lengths as I can figure it out from the quotes.  here is an example of this part with your text in A1 (repeated down in a column for all entries you have - I am displaying 3 columns here)

```
=FIND("""", A1) =FIND("""", $A1, B1 + 1)    =FIND("""", $A1, C1 + 1)
```

Then on sheet1, I calculate your headings on the first row like this (Displaying 2 columns here)

```
=MID(Sheet2!$A$1, Sheet2!B1 +1,Sheet2!C1 - Sheet2!B1 - 1) =MID(Sheet2!$A$1,Sheet2!F1 +1, Sheet2!G1 - Sheet2!F1 - 1)
```

Then on each row I calculate each column value like this. (Displaying 2 columns here

```
=MID(Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!D1 +1, Sheet2!E1 - Sheet2!D1 - 1) =MID(Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!H1 +1, Sheet2!I1 - Sheet2!H1 - 1)
```

each of these can be blocked and dragged down for as many rows as you need.

I am trying to figure out how to send you a copy of the sheet....

[image: Sheet 2]

[image: Sheet 1]

Full spreadsheet text Sheet 1 Row 1

```
=MID(Sheet2!$A$1, Sheet2!B1 +1,Sheet2!C1 - Sheet2!B1 - 1) 
=MID(Sheet2!$A$1,Sheet2!F1 +1, Sheet2!G1 - Sheet2!F1 - 1) 
=MID(Sheet2!$A$1, Sheet2!J1 +1, Sheet2!K1 - Sheet2!J1 - 1) 
=MID(Sheet2!$A$1, Sheet2!N1 +1, Sheet2!O1 - Sheet2!N1 - 1)
```

Sheet 1 Row 2 (Box drag this one down for every row of data you have

```
=MID(Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!D1 +1, Sheet2!E1 - Sheet2!D1 - 1)
=MID(Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!H1 +1, Sheet2!I1 - Sheet2!H1 - 1)
=MID(Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!L1 +1, Sheet2!M1 - Sheet2!L1 - 1)
=MID(Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!P1 +1, Sheet2!Q1 - Sheet2!P1 - 1)
```

Sheet 2 Row 1  (Box drag this one down for every row you have)

```
"formid";s:4:"1001";s:11:"mkto_MRM_ID";s:6:"287227";s:15:"Activity_Name_m";s:59:"ca erwin data modeler community edition evaluation software";s:13:"CSU_Driver__c";s:0:""
=FIND("""", A1)
=FIND("""", $A1, B1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, C1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, D1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, E1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, F1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, G1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, H1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, I1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, J1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, K1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, L1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, M1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, N1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, O1 + 1)
=FIND("""", $A1, P1 + 1)
```

Comment: Hi,
I think the macro shown above is good because it seems to offer the most flexibility.

As mentioned above,  
 
 It seems to work until it encounters the first 0 value in the upcoming string length. So in the above example if the MRM string was length zero then it seems to quit evaluating the rest of the fields. If MRM is present then it seems to go on and evaluate other strings. The real data always starts with what you see above, but it has more fields than shown so the idea is to have it parse through everything even if some of the preceding fields are blank / length 0.

Answer (score 0):

So it still looks like you may not have what you want here or what I put in the other answer was too complicated.  So here is a VBA way to do it.  All you need to do (using this exact code) is place all of rows of data into column A.  It will transpose your headers and rows two columns to the right.  Cheers.

```
Sub parseAndBuild()
    Dim i, j, pos As Integer
    Dim val As String
    Dim item As String

    i = 1
    j = 1
    pos = 1

    'Build the headers
    val = Cells(1, 1).value
    Do
        item = getNextItem(pos, val)
        Cells(1, i + 2).value = item
        getNextItem pos, val
        i = i + 1
    Loop While item <> ""

    i = 1
    'build the rows
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i))
        val = Cells(i, 1).value
        j = 1
        pos = 1
        Do
            'ignore first as it is header and lengths
            item = getNextItem(pos, val)

            item = getNextItem(pos, val)
            Cells(i + 1, j + 2).value = item
            j = j + 1

        Loop While item <> ""
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Function getNextItem(pos As Integer, val As String)
    Dim pos1, pos2 As Integer

    pos1 = InStr(pos, val, """")
    pos2 = InStr(pos1 + 1, val, """")
    If (pos1 <> 0 And pos2 <> 0) Then
        pos = pos2 + 1
        getNextItem = Mid$(val, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1)
    Else
        getNextItem = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Everyone,
Thanks for chiming in.  Been such a crazy day that I didn't have a chance to review everyone's responses.  

My boss found a solution that we think is working although not necessarily as elegant as some of what is posted above.  I'm going to go through the data now using what he has done and if it's working then great, otherwise I will be back to review these in more detail with an eye toward finding a more comprehensive solution.

Candidly I"m amazed by the speed and sophistication of the replies.

Thanks again,
Phils

Comment: Thanks phil, remember to vote any solutions up that you like and make answered if we solve your problem. This helps make the site work.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it works up to a point.  It seems to work until it encounters the first 0 value in the upcoming string length.  So in the above example if the MRM string was length zero then it seems to quit evaluating the rest of the fields.  If MRM is present then it seems to go on and evaluate other strings.

The real data always starts with what you see above, but it has more fields than shown so the idea is to have it parse through everything even if some of the preceding fields are blank (length zero).  But this does show promise since when the MRM is present it does work.

Comment: Hi,
I attempted chewy's method with the excel formulas and made another discovery about the data.  The order and number of the fields is not constant.  So using Row 1 to derive the column names and field lengths and then applying it to the other rows does not work.

So row one might have 5 fields/items A,B,D,E,F while row 2 might have A,B,C,D,E

Seems like one option is to build a list of all fields and create fixed columns with all the names and then have the parsing use the column head to try find that matching label in the data and then parsed for the subsequent value that might work.

Comment: I think I'm now looking for something like this.
If the value in the heading can be found in the data
Advance to the quote following that field and return the value between the next two quotes.

So, instead of strictly using quotes to determine fields and values I would look for a string/label matching my column head and then return the associated value.  First search for the string and then use some logic to find the first quote following, then the second quote and return what is in between.  Just keep in mind that both the label and it's value are surrounded by quotes.
Thank you,
Phil